# Exception C# null list

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am filling a list from an XML file. Some nodes may not exist and this causes an exception because it returns null. Here is the code:

```
public static List<Compte> getXmlComptes(string pathXml)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(pathXml);
    var comptes = doc.Descendants("Anzeige").Descendants("Kunde").Descendants("Konto").Select(p => new Compte()
    {
        NumCompte = p.Element("KtoNr") != null ? p.Element("KtoNr").Value : String.Empty,
        typeCompte = p.Element("KontoArt") != null ? p.Element("KontoArt").Value : String.Empty,

        Trans = getXmlTransactions(pathXml)
    }).ToList();

    return comptes;
}
```

How can I make a controf before adding items to the list. Thank you.

exemple of the xml file :

```
<Anzeige>
   <Kunde>
      <IdClient>ppp</IdClient>
      <Konto>
           <NumCompte>258</NumCompte>
           <Transaction>
                <idTrans>85555</idTrans>
                <type>blebleble</type>
           </Transaction>
           <Transaction>
                <idTrans>85555</idTrans>
                <type>blebleble</type>
           </Transaction>
       </Konto>
    </Kunde>
</Anzeige>
```

code of getXmlTransaction :

```
public static List<Transaction> getXmlTransactions(string pathXml)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(pathXml);

    var transactions = doc.Descendants("Anzeige").Descendants("Kunde").Descendants("Konto").Descendants("Transaktion").Select(p => new Transaction()
        {
            TransID = p.Element("TransID") != null ? p.Element("TransID").Value : String.Empty,
            TypeTransaction = p.Element("TransArt") != null ? p.Element("TransArt").Value : String.Empty

        }).ToList();

    if (transactions != null)
        return transactions.ToList();
    else
        return new List<Transaction>();
}
```

Comment: Most likely you have exception in `getXmlTransactions(pathXml)` call. I showed several hints on parsing xml when nodes not exist in my answer, but you need to show that method definition (and xml you are trying to parse)

Comment: the content of getXmlTransaction(pathxml) is the same of getXmlComptes ,I called it because the Compte contains a list of transactions

Comment: I think it's not same. Also its not good re-loading whole xml to get child nodes of some element

Comment: I edited it, take a look and tell me, I think the problem is when there is no node <Konto>

Comment: I rolled back your edits. If you have another question, ask another questin

Answer (score 3):

Use casting of element to string instead of reading it's value directly. If element was not found, you will have `null` string instead of exception:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(pathXml);
var comptes = doc.Descendants("Anzeige")
                 .Descendants("Kunde")
                 .Descendants("Konto")
                 .Select(k => new Compte {
                     NumCompte = (string)k.Element("KtoNr"),
                     typeCompte = (string)k.Element("KontoArt"),
                     Trans = getXmlTransactions(k)
                  }).ToList();
```

If you want empty string instead of `null` when element not found, you can use [null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator

```
NumCompte = (string)p.Element("KtoNr") ?? ""
```

Use same technique for parsing nodes which may not exist. And I'm pretty sure that it's `getXmlTransactions(pathXml)` method throws exception.

UPDATE: Do not load whole xml document when you are getting transactions. How would you know which Konto element transactions to read. Pass Konto element instead and get its transactions:

```
public static List<Transaction> getXmlTransactions(XElement konto)
{
    return konto.Elements("Transaction")
                .Select(t => new Transaction {
                     TransID = (string)t.Element("idTrans"),
                     TypeTransaction = (string)t.Element("type")
                }).ToList();
}
```

NOTE: You have `<idTrans>` (instead `TransID`) and `<type>` (instead `TransArt`) elements in `<Transaction>` (instead `Transaktion`)! Also there is no `KtoNr` and `KontoArt` elements in your xml. Read element names carefully. Also instead of looking for all descendants it's better to search in direct children:

```
doc.Root.Elements("Kunde").Elements("Konto") ...
```

Comment: Won't whis still throw when for example `.Descendants("Kunde")` isn't present?

Comment: @CodeCaster no, if `Kunde` not found, `Descendants` will return empty sequence

Comment: @CodeCaster I believe in `getXmlTransactions(pathXml)` - maybe he accesses some node value directly. I will ask him to update question with that method code

Comment: No the problem is when <Konto> is not present, it returns a null list, so it causes the exception

Comment: @user1503496 no, if `Konto` is not present `Descendants("Knoto")` will return empty sequence. Converting that sequence to list will give you empty list

Comment: @user1503496 show `getXmlTransactions(pathXml)` and xml which gives you error

Comment: Yes I wrote an example of the xml file , it is not the right one. Ok thanks for the help, but if it doesn't find the node"Konto" it will return null ,sin't it? and it is the same problem i think because there is no condition on the xmlelement , i guess

Comment: @user1503496 no, if this method was called, then `konto` is not null

Comment: How can I call the XElement?

Comment: @user1503496 which XElement?

Comment: It's ok about the Xelement, but the same Exception : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. cause the node trasaktion is not present in the xml file

Comment: @user1503496 you have that problem elsewhere. `Descendants("Transaktion")` return empty collection if there is no `Transaktion` elements in file. No exceptions will be thrown. Use approach which I shown to you. Do not access `Value` property or any other members of element if it can be null. If you will use exactly same code as I provided, you will not get any exceptions. You are using something different if you still have error

Comment: Sergey take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305675/xml-element-not-present-and-list-null-and-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instanc

Comment: @user1503496 why you are still trying to access `Value` property?

Comment: because i did it without the String.empty and it returned a null value and an exception