# Xml Element not present and list null and Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list, linq-to-xml

I am retireving data from xml field, there are nodes that may not exist (because the xml file is generated dynamically) . the problem is when I look for a node and it is not present in the file , it returns a null list and this exception :"d Object reference not set to an instance of an object ". 
Here is the code :

```
public static List<Transaction> getXmlTransactions(XElement n)
        {


            var transactions = n.Elements("Transaktion").Select(p => new Transaction()
                {
                    TransID = p.Element("TransID") != null ? p.Element("TransID").Value : String.Empty,
                    TypeTransaction = p.Element("TransArt") != null ? p.Element("TransArt").Value : String.Empty,
                    DateEntree = p.Element("BuchDat") != null ? p.Element("BuchDat").Value : String.Empty,
                    Montant = p.Element("BetragWAE") != null ? p.Element("BetragWAE").Value : String.Empty,
                    Devise = p.Element("BuchDat") != null ? p.Element("Waehrung").Value : String.Empty,
                    // BanqueCorespondante = p.Element("BuchDat") != null ? p.Element("Waehrung").Value : String.Empty,   Dans le compte
                    Pays = p.Element("GegenLandText") != null ? p.Element("GegenLandText").Value : String.Empty,
                    AbreviationPays = p.Element("GegenLand") != null ? p.Element("GegenLand").Value : String.Empty,
                    autresinfo = p.Element("Kommentar") != null ? p.Element("Kommentar").Value : String.Empty
                }).ToList();


                return transactions;



        } 

 public static List<Compte> getXmlComptes(XElement n)
        {


            var comptes = n.Elements("Konto").Select(p => new Compte()
            {
                NumCompte = p.Element("KtoNr") != null ? p.Element("KtoNr").Value : String.Empty,
                typeCompte = p.Element("KontoArt") != null ? p.Element("KontoArt").Value : String.Empty,
                DateOuverture = p.Element("KtoOeff") != null ? p.Element("KtoOeff").Value : String.Empty,
                IBAN = p.Element("IBAN") != null ? p.Element("IBAN").Value : String.Empty,
                Devise = p.Element("Waehrung") != null ? p.Element("Waehrung").Value : String.Empty,
                CommentairesCompte = p.Element("Kommentar") != null ? p.Element("Kommentar").Value : String.Empty,
                Trans = getXmlTransactions(p)
            }).ToList();


                return comptes;

        }
```

Comment: Side note - just return `comptes` and `transactions` without `ToList()` call - both are already lists

Comment: At which statement do you receive error?

Comment: sorry , yes i rectified this, but the same exception stills. the exception is in the getXmlTransaction (select newTrasaction() ....)

Comment: @user1503496 so, what you see when you run my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From code you provided I can say, that you are passing `null` to `getXmlComptes` method (or to `getXmlTransactions` if it is called elsewhere).

I suggest you to cast elements:

```
public static List<Transaction> getXmlTransactions(XElement n)
{
   if (n == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("Konto is null");

    var transactions = from t in n.Elements("Transaktion")
                       select new Transaction {
                           TransID = (string)t.Element("TransID"),
                           TypeTransaction = (string)t.Element("TransArt"),
                           DateEntree = (string)t.Element("BuchDat"),
                           Montant = (string)t.Element("BetragWAE"),
                           Devise = (string)t.Element("BuchDat"),
                           Pays = (string)t.Element("GegenLandText"),
                           AbreviationPays = (string)t.Element("GegenLand"),
                           autresinfo = (string)t.Element("Kommentar")
                       };

    return transactions.ToList();
}
```

And second method:

```
public static List<Compte> getXmlComptes(XElement n)
{
   if (n == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("Something is null");

    var comptes = from k in n.Elements("Konto")
                  select new Compte
                  {
                      NumCompte = (string)k.Element("KtoNr"),
                      typeCompte = (string)k.Element("KontoArt"),
                      DateOuverture = (string)k.Element("KtoOeff"),
                      IBAN = (string)k.Element("IBAN"),
                      Devise = (string)k.Element("Waehrung"),
                      CommentairesCompte = (string)k.Element("Kommentar"),
                      Trans = getXmlTransactions(k)
                  };

    return comptes.ToList();
}
```

Run this code and you'll see were you are passing `null`. If you need to assign empty string to some property if element is missing in xml, then use null-coalescing operator:

```
TypeTransaction = (string)t.Element("TransArt") ?? ""
```

But I would keep property value as `null` to show that it was not in xml.

Comment: Its ok, but take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306482/item-in-a-list-of-a-list-is-not-beeing-displayed

Comment: @user1503496 sorry, didn't get you. Does this code parses your xml? If you have some error, then please provide error details and point which line of code thrown exception

Comment: this code works fine. now in the other question where i want to display the clients , data is stored correctly but it does not display the value , i think it displays the type of the value nomClient